# Why does my plumbing shut itself off?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater

I had a water leak when my shower supply line broke. The plumber had to shut off the water main and replace the shutoff at the water meter and shower diverter. Now when I turn on my kitchen sink hot water runs for 3 minutes then I lose pressure and the water goes off. The pipes knock a little but no air comes out of the faucet.

Is this an air pocket in the hot water heater?

Comment: Does the cold water also shut off? Do other faucets function the same way or is it just the kitchen faucet?

Comment: Did you check the cold water inlet valve on the hot water heater?  It's possible that the valve is partially closed, which would allow your expansion tank to pressurize slowly over time.  The pressure from the tank would supply hot water to your faucet for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Check the cold water inlet valve on the hot water heater. It's possible that the valve is partially closed, which would allow your expansion tank to pressurize slowly over time. The pressure from the tank would supply hot water to your faucet for a while.